# How to read and write data in FS82 Finger Print Scanner?

Tags: asp.net

How to read and write data in FS82 Finger Print Scanner ?. Kindly provide me the solution in asp.net. I need to read finger print from this device. And readed finger print need to store in smart card using same this device.

Answer (score 0):

Use its API http://www.futronic-tech.com/product_sdk_win.html

Most likely you cannot do it "in asp.net", because the device needs to be connected somewhere at client side and asp.net application runs on a server.